Identify this South Indian movie in which the male character files a missing complaint about his uncle
In this movie's plot, the guy filed a missing complaint about his uncle. A senior inspector, after reading a newspaper article, starts searching for this person.
After every new piece of evidence is found, the police become more and more confused about the true identity of the man and his uncle.

Welcome to Movies & TV SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you watched the movie or TV show (even an approximate year or decade is helpful), and what movies or TV shows you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

This film seems very well described with no less 9 relevant pieces of information to go on (movie/South Indian/male lead/missing uncle/missing person report/senior investigator reads article/investigation into missing person is main element of film/confusing evidence about the missing person and the person who filed the complaint). I'm at a loss why people would be trying to close it.

This is IIT Krishnamurthy (2020).

Krishnamurthy, who is an IIT Bombay student comes to Hyderabad and gets to know that his uncle is missing. The entire story revolves around the mysterious missing case of Krishnamurthy's uncle.




